# Shopware : Order data extraction on subscribed event

Tags: php, shopware

I need an ordered products SKU and Name on subscribed event,

Subscribed Event :

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'Shopware_Modules_Order_SaveOrder_ProcessDetails' => 'getAccountController'

        ];

    }
```

I need to extract an ordered product data. These products stock update to external sources. I am done with API testing with a static parameter. I need a dynamic parameter from shopware i.e. product SKU and ordered QTY of that product (Product may be in single or multiple in order).

```
 /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAccountController(Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args)
    {
        $basketContent = $args-> getDetails ();
        $order = $args-> getSubject ();
        $orderNumber = $order->sOrderNumber;

 //       var_dump ($basketContent);
   //     exit;

        $token = "mytoken";

        // Organization which Manage warehouse and other things
        $orgNo = "1";

        // An SKU or Number must same as both site e-commerce and korona

        $productNumber = "demo.product";

        $qty = 10; // QTY you want to update Minus (-) indicate 

        // Create an API Object 
        $APIObject = new APIHelper();
        $response = $APIObject->StockAdjustment($token,$orgNo,$productNumber,$qty);        
        //Enter Response in table for log purpose
        //$response=mysql_real_escape_string(stripcslashes($response));
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `s_plugin_Sa_log` (`id`, `response_desc`) VALUES (NULL, '$response')";            
        Shopware()->Db()->query($sql);
        return ;        
    }
```

**Complete Code**

```
<?php
namespace SwagAPI\Subscribers;
use SwagAPI\APIAPI;
use Enlight\Event\SubscriberInterface;

class APISubscriber extends APIHelper implements SubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * Subscribe an event when API code will be execute
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'Shopware_Modules_Order_SaveOrder_ProcessDetails' => 'getAccountController'

        ];

    }


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAccountController()
    {

        //Static Token 
        $token = "MY Token";

        // Organization which Manage warehouse and other things
        $orgNo = "1";

        $this->session = Shopware()->Session();
        $ZT_Core_Product =  $this->session['sOrderVariables']['sBasketProportional']['content'];
        $APIProductsArray = array();
        // A SKU or Number must same as both site ecommerce and API
        //productnumber => qty
        foreach ($ZT_Core_Product as $key => $value) {
            $ProductSKU  = $value['ordernumber'];
            $APIProductsArray[$ProductSKU ] = -1 * abs($value['quantity']);           
        }

        // Create an API Object 
        $APIObject = new APIHelper();
        $response = $APIObject->StockAdjustment($token,$orgNo,$APIProductsArray);        

        //Enter Response in table for log purpose        
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `s_plugin_SwagAPI_log` (`id`, `response_desc`) VALUES (NULL, '$response')";            
        Shopware()->Db()->query($sql);
        return ;        
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The products' data of an order are passed in the array `details`. You can collect the needed data by e.g. looping over the array:

```
public function getAccountController(Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args)
{
    $basketContent = $args->get('details');

    foreach ($basketContent as $article) {
        $quantity = $article['quantity'];
        $sku = $article['ordernumber'];
        $name = $article['articlename'];
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: get an error while use this `Enlight_Event_EventArgs` becuase getAccountController() not method of class.

Comment: @vasimShaikh it should work. Can you post your entire class and the service definition from your `services.xml` file?

Comment: give me moment. This is a subscribed event

Comment: @vasimShaikh Can you post the complete error stack trace?

Comment: I have sort out issue by removing that `Enlight_Event_EventArgs`

Comment: Ok, the class `Enlight_Event_EventArgs` shouldn't cause any problems, but still a nice workaround.

Comment: getAccountController is not method

Comment: How to integrate cron job get a stock from External shop